# Decode and stream h264 over udp with GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, tegra

I'm trying to decode a video from h264 and reencode it to transfer to a client trhough udp:

On the transmitter side:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/home/ubuntu/Videos/test.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! nvvidconv ! omxh264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

On the receiver side:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! nveglglessink
```

I do it locally, for a test, on an NVidia Tegra TK1, but nothing is being displayed although no error is being raised.

Does anybody see something to add? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that work on your full PC? Honestly, though being an interesting piece of hardware, the tegra is an embedded device, and unless you heavily optimize your software, the poor thing usually won't be the favourite thing to do compute-intense loads. *If* you optimize, you might be able to do things that you would otherwise need a lot more Watt/space, but it's not like you should develop algorithms *on* the embeddded device -- you typically do the testing and development on a PC with a proper GPU, which would be much faster, and then slim down your application until it runs on the Tegra.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally made it work, but using an other network protocol:

Just for testing, send and receive locally on the Tegra TK1 itself:

Send:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/ubuntu/Videos/test.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! nvvidconv ! omxh264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

Receive:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! nveglglessink sync=false
```

Result is choppy, but I don't care at this stage. I receive something!!

Receive on Ubuntu PC:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=<Tegra IP> port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```